# OpenSSL warning notice for bridge

Tags: configuration, bridge

I get the warning below when starting running a bridge.

Should I change the torrc file, or do something else, to deal with this problem, or should I ignore the message?

Apr 14 06:16:02.385 [warn] OpenSSL version from headers does not match the version we're running with. If you get weird crashes, that might be why. (Compiled with 1000207f: OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016; running with 1000207f: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016).

Apr 14 06:16:02.430 [notice] Tor 0.3.2.10 (git-0edaa32732ec8930) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable, OpenSSL 1.0.2g, Zlib 1.2.8, Liblzma 5.1.0alpha, and Libzstd N/A.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you compiled the tor yourself, there seems to be some compatibility issues in the libraries.

Try to instal  pre buit tor from a repository.

For debian based:

```
 sudo apt install tor
```

Also try to update all your libs

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```